# Is It Possible to Return the Sum from addmargins()

Tags: r

I am working with a motor vehicle thefts dataset.
[image]

I created a Month column, then a two-way table based on Month and Arrest.

```
addmargins(table(vehicle_thefts$Month, vehicle_thefts$Arrest))
```

[image]

Is it possible to return just the total number of thefts (191,641)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be simpler to use

```
tbl <- table(vehicle_thefts$Month, vehicle_thefts$Arrest)
sum(tbl)
```

But if you really need to get it from `addmargins`:

```
addmargins(tbl)[nrow(tbl)+1, ncol(tbl)+1]
```